# Flask: how to get rid of pdfkit causing 500 Error

Tags: python, python-pdfkit

I'm getting errors while trying to create a .pdf file with my Flask application's pdfkit. The application does work on a local machine. The problems start to appear when I try to run the code on Digitalocean's Ubuntu 18.04 droplet (Nginx is used as a web server, Gunicorn (assisted by a supervisor) runs wsgi). That's the error (500) I'm getting inside of a browser:

> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in
>   the application.

That's the error from the Gunicorn's error log:

```
[2019-07-27 14:44:56,969] ERROR in app: Exception on /store/resins/daylight/3 [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/slava/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/slava/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/slava/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/slava/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/slava/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/slava/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/slava/ag3d/ag3d/routes.py", line 184, in resin_store
    pdfkit.from_string(rendered, pdf_name, options = options)
  File "/home/slava/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pdfkit/api.py", line 72, in from_string
    return r.to_pdf(output_path)
  File "/home/slava/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pdfkit/pdfkit.py", line 159, in to_pdf
    raise IOError("wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code {0}. error:\n{1}".format(exit_code, stderr))
OSError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error:
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Could not connect to any X display.
```

This is how the application uses pdfkit:

```
options = {
  'page-size': 'A4',
  'margin-top': '0.75in',
  'margin-right': '0.75in',
  'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
  'margin-left': '0.75in',
}
rendered = render_template('order_doc.html', pdf_resin = pdf_resin)
pdfkit.from_string(rendered, pdf_name, options = options)
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192646/89845

Comment: or you can try following package
https://pypi.org/project/headless-pdfkit/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply @TalhaJunaid .Any idea on how'd the process of running wkhtmltopdf inside of the xvfb look like in my case? Can't find the installation instructions in that repo.

Comment: try running `xvfb-run` it might be already there

Comment: Just try the `headless-pdfkit` without scratching head with `xvfb-run`. I think it will work.

Comment: The headless-pdfkit does the trick. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The PDFKit package makes use of `wkhtmltopdf`, which in turn needs an X Server to run. In Debian land, this generally requires `xvfb-run` wrapper.

The [headless_pdfkit](https://pypi.org/project/headless-pdfkit/) package tries to make the [hotfix](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/issues/56#issuecomment-305593936) proposed by [jakewins](https://github.com/jakewins) a bit easier to work with.

You can install `headless_pdfkit` by running:

```
pip install headless-pdfkit
```

Save a simple PDF from string.:

```
from headless_pdfkit import generate_pdf

ret = generate_pdf('<html></html>')
with open('output.pdf', 'wb') as w:
    w.write(ret)

options = {
    'auto_servernum': ''
}

ret = generate_pdf('<html></html>', options=options)
with open('output.pdf', 'wb') as w:
    w.write(ret)
```